# Visual Studio Alt and Arrow Up/Down is not working

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is not working in Visual Studio. Some people don't use it, but for those who do it's annoying when it's not there.

I expect the shortcuts to move the selected lines up/down.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Go to Tools\Options... in the menu, then Environment\Keyboard in the tree view and search for

- Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown, and
- Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp

Add global shortcuts for them: Alt+Down Arrow and Alt+Up Arrow respectively.

[image: Screenshot from Visual Studio 2019]

Comment: For Resharper users, I also had to unset two shortcuts: `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextMethod` and `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoPrevMethod`

Comment: Not sure why setting the `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown` wasn't enough; shouldn't it override the ReSharper settings? Setting both also did the trick for me.
I would have never found the hidden ReSharper keyboard setting without you!

Comment: a one step solution is to just go to Tools->Options->General->Keyboard and reset defaults with Visual C# 2006 option

Comment: If you select "Text Editor" instead of "Global" in "Use new shortcut in:", it will ask if you want it to override the ReSharper shortcut. At least that's what worked for me right now.

Answer (score 15):

Below steps fixed for me (includes resetting to default) in Visual Studio 2019  (16.11.x) +  ReSharper 2021.2:

1. Extensions -> ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Shortcut Scheme
2. Select "None" and hit Apply Scheme button then Save button
3. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
4. Select (Default) in dropdown and hit Reset button (on top)
5. Go to step #1
6. Select "Visual Studio" and hit Apply Scheme button then Save button
7. Go to step #3
8. Find "**ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextMember**" and click on Remove button
9. Find "**ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoPrevMember**" and click on Remove button
10. Find "**Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp**" assign Alt + Up Arrow
11. Find "**Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown**" assign Alt + Down Arrow

Comment: This fixed it, thank you.  Still a problem with R# 2023.1.